# A visual subject in group theory

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, intuition

My math teacher gave us the following instruction: « Pick any subject of your choice (in math of course) and in 2 months present it to the class ».

I really like this idea, and I really like group theory hence I am looking for an interesting/intuitive subject in group theory which has visual results/theorems.

I know the basics of group theory: Lagrange theorem, Sylow theorems, group actions, the structure of finite abelian groups, Cayley graphs...

For example, I looked briefly at Lie groups and representation theory but this is far too complicated for me and I feel like there’s a huge gap between the above results and these two fields.

I’ve also looked at the braid group which is very interesting but it seems to me like there aren’t so many things that can be said about this group (except studying the word problem on this group).

Here is, briefly, what I know in maths: linear algebra (vector spaces, matrices, reduction, Jordan...), topology (only the topology of normed vector spaces), analysis (Riemann integration, ...).

Thank you in advance!
(if you are not sure don’t hesitate to post suggestions in the comment section :) )

Comment: This could be too broad (and opinion based) of a question, but you could look at the "symmetry of necklaces". This involves group theory and combinatorics and has some neat visual interpretations. If that sounds like it may interest you, check out [Pólya's enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem).

Comment: I suggest to look into permutation groups and their visualization with Rubik's cube. You can study e.g. concepts like equivalent elements, commutators, subgroups, conservation laws (similar but more sophisticated than in Sam Loyd's 15-puzzle). For details see https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~burkej/cube/singmaster.pdf

Comment: Given what you say you know, i'm surprised you feel as if representation theory were too hard. I think you could really be interested by it. One example of a result that seems accessible given your background is to use (the basics of) representation theory to prove that $S_n$ cannot be generated by less than $n-1$ transpositions (result which can also be proved by some graph combinatorics)

Comment: @Guido A. This is interesting, thank you for the proposition.

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze This is definitely a nice application of group theory, I’ll look more deeply in the file you have tomorrow.

Comment: @Max Maybe you are right. Actually I looked at some pdf file about representation theory, and it felt like a bunch of definitions to me, and quickly it becames hard for me to get intuition whereas the goal of representation theory is to get visual intuition about group (just as the intuition for vector spaces). Nevertheless maybe I’ll give it an other try since your application is interesting. Is there a central theorem in representation theory which is quite intuitive and powerful ? Are there other visual result we can get thanks to representation theory ? Ty for your answer.

Comment: have you looked up geometric group theory?

Comment: You could present the symmetries of the five platonic solids, i.e. the tetrahedron, the cube, the octahedron, the dodecahedron and the icosahedron. First of all, you could present it quite visually (showing pictures, animations, bringing physical dice etc.) And the symmetric groups of the dodecahedron and icosahedron might surprise you. I'd be happy to discuss it with you if you want.